# Different layout between Scene builder preview and program in execution

Tags: java, css, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

When I execute my program, the interface is different from the scene builder preview. This problem is driving me crazy. What can i do to solve this problem?
[Preview vs Result in execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5nM1.jpg)
FXML

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

        <?import java.lang.*?>
        <?import java.net.*?>
        <?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
        <?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
        <?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
        <?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
        <?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

        <AnchorPane prefHeight="425.0" prefWidth="242.0" styleClass="background" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="application.FirstController">
          <children>
            <Hyperlink layoutX="53.0" layoutY="357.0" text="Password dimenticata?" textFill="#33e7ff">
              <stylesheets>
                <URL value="@application.css" />
              </stylesheets>
            </Hyperlink>
            <TextField fx:id="txtUsername" layoutX="15.0" layoutY="231.0" prefWidth="207.0" promptText="Username" />
            <Separator layoutX="13.0" layoutY="345.0" prefHeight="4.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
            <Separator layoutX="16.0" layoutY="220.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
            <Button id="btnConferma" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="301.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefWidth="99.0" text="Conferma" />
            <Button id="btnAnnulla" layoutX="123.0" layoutY="301.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefWidth="99.0" text="Annulla" />
            <Text layoutX="92.0" layoutY="79.0" scaleX="3.5060922995036727" scaleY="2.63215859030837" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="CARLOAN">
              <fill>
                <Color blue="1.000" green="0.522" red="0.200" fx:id="x1" />
              </fill>
            </Text>
            <Text fill="$x1" layoutX="189.0" layoutY="110.0" scaleX="1.3491931995059285" scaleY="1.313264806656877" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="V1.0" />
            <TextArea id="areaTesto" editable="false" layoutX="19.0" layoutY="146.0" prefHeight="67.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="&#10;" text="Benvenuto in CarLoan! Per favore effettua il login per utilizzare tutte le funzionalità del sistema." wrapText="true">
              <stylesheets>
                <URL value="@application.css" />
              </stylesheets>
            </TextArea>
            <PasswordField fx:id="txtPassword" layoutX="15.0" layoutY="270.0" prefWidth="207.0" promptText="Password" />
          </children>
          <stylesheets>
            <URL value="@application.css" />
          </stylesheets>
        </AnchorPane>
```

This is the css: http://pastebin.com/NWTT8DAa

I'm using a lot of Pattern for this Project. In particular, I have a front controller in main class of package and a dispatcher where is executed the view exchange. I'm posting the main classe and the method that change the view:

MAIN CLASS:

```
        package application;

import Eccezioni.Eccezione;
import presentation.tier.FrontController;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static final Stage stage = new Stage();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Eccezione {
        try {
            FrontController fc = null;
            fc = FrontController.getInstance();
            fc.handleRequest("openViewStart", null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Eccezione("Impossibile lanciare il programma..");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

And this is the DISPATCHING METHOD:

```
        private void apriViewStart() throws Eccezione {
        try {
            AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/Login.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/application/application.css").toExternalForm());
            Main.stage.setTitle("CarLoan 1.0");
            Main.stage.setScene(scene);
            Main.stage.show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Eccezione("Impossibile caricare l'interfaccia.");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Exe? Why exe? *Exe*plain please. (normally I'd expect this to be a jar or a folder structure containing the `.class` files)

Comment: Post your FXML, and CSS if you have a stylesheet, along with the code to run it.

Comment: I'm sorry lol with exe I mean when I execute my program in Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but the Scene Builder preview and the execution gui are different. To solve this problem I had to change some parameters in my CSS code